# Is it possible to have a Windows Phone 7.x application update variables from an online source?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am working on a currency converter program, and I am attempting to allow the program to update all of the conversion rates from an online source, so that the currency conversion is always up to date. Can this be done, and can anyone give me an idea on a better way of phrasing what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: Well what have you tried? Do you already have an online source which does what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data in a file in isolated storage or in a SQL CE database. You can then check if there are new versions of data online periodically or on application start and then update the data inside.

To check if there is new data online, you need to either reuse an existing service or provide your own.

Answer (score 0):

For your Wp7 App, you need fresh Data of **Conversion Rates**. Since a device may not be always connected to Internet, so you would be storing your Data in one of the ways.
A few can be:

- Storing Data in a "Text File" or **Xml** in Isolated Storage
- Using a Database to store your Data, like inbuilt **SQL CE** or others like **SQLite** or **Sterling**

To bring fresh Data (i.e. Conversion Rates in your Case), you need to connect to a Web Service over Http to fetch data. The service may be your **own hosted** or a **third party**.